# Bar-codes and Excel Spreadsheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, barcode-scanner

I've been asked by our warehouse guy to help him with an excel spreadsheet to increase his productivity. The problem is, I'm not what you would call an "excel expert". What he wants sounds very simple, I'm just not sure how to do it.

Right now he has a USB barcode scanner. When he scans to an excel spreadsheet he would like to scan the UPC code of an item and have it automatically change to our actual part number. Can this be done? Please let me know if you would like additional information

For Example: 
UPC = 38568963772
Item# = AF5155

**Edit:**

[image: New Excel File]

this show what we are trying to scan the UPC codes into.

[image: Database example]

this is a simple two column file pulled from our system.

Comment: You would need a database of all your products UPC codes and their corresponding Item numbers, for the spreadsheet to reference. Access would probably be better suited for this task.

Comment: @wysiwyg Thank you for the response. I do have a database ready to go. Just not sure how to reference in excel.

Comment: Excel is extremely capable.  So what you want is certainly doable depending on what type of database it is.  Many tutorials online that explain how to get started

Comment: You can use vlookup but the result will be in a second column where you write the formula, it will not replace UPC, edit your question and write an example(your database sheet and the new sheet)

Comment: @yass Thank you, I've added a couple images as I was unable to lay it out like I had hoped. Let me know if that is enough or additional information is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In another place in the workbook (different sheet would be neatest), have a 2 column list of UPC code and part number.

Then, in the column next to where the UPC appears, use VLOOKUP:

```
=vlookup( [cell with UPC code] , [range with the two columns of data], 2, False)
```

Make sure the reference to the range is static, eg $a$3:$b$50, so if you fill the formula down the column of scanned codes the reference doesn't change.

Alternatively, if the part number needs to actually replace the UPC code, you'd need to write a macro to fire on cell changes, but this is a fair bit more work.

Comment: If it's a small database, you could program all of the UPC codes into the custom autocorrect.  Obviously that could get unwieldy very quickly.